# Is it reasonable to abstract out database tables?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I maintain an app that has many modules. Each of these modules can have comments on its items. For example, an "Assessments" module which contains assessments, a "Projects" module which contains projects, and a "Findings" module which contains findings.

Currently, I have a "comments" table for each of these items. Example table list:

```
assessments
assessments_comments (id, assessment_id, comment)
projects
projects_comments (id, project_id, comment)
findings
findings_comments (id, finding_id, comment)
```

Does it make sense to abstract the comments to one table? Ex:

```
assessments
projects
findings
comments (id, entity, entity_id, comment) i.e.(1, 'assessments', 1, 'this is a comment')
```

I don't think I will ever need a list of all comments in the app. Generally, what are some good questions to ask when considering abstraction?

Comment: I'm surprised you don't have a timestamp and user_id on your comments. Might there be further metadata that's different within different modules? Then as soon as you get a difference in schema, you'd have difficulties smashing them into the same table.

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? Follow a published presentation of a published design method. Don't ask us to (re)write one. Ask 1 question re the 1st place you are stuck. Basic questions are duplicates. We cannot tell you what is "best". You need to define it. Then tell about how you are stuck applying it. [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)
[Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you've carried out a thorough enough needs analysis yet/a single `comment` field seems inadequate to capture why business users typically record comments. But if it's q's for probing the design you're looking for:

How are the `id`s generated? Are they unique across all modules? Then wherever you're generating them from might suffer poor concurrency characteristics.

Are `assessment_id, project_id, finding_id` of the same type? Is each `_id` unique across all modules? Then again you'll get concurrency/contention difficulties in generating them.

Don't `project`s etc have 'natural keys' determined by the users, rather than artificially generated surrogate keys? And shouldn't you be indexing everything by natural keys? Then same q's: are those various natural keys the same type in each module? (That seems hard to believe.) Trying to smash them into a cross-module index is asking for trouble.